# How to change boot drive name?

Tags: nvme, remapping

I am having trouble installing additional nvme sticks, and it seems that my new stick takes over boot drive's name, like /dev/dba

I used to have

- /dev/nvme0n1: my storage1
- /dev/nvme1n1: my storage2
- /dev/nvme2n1: my boot stick
- /dev/sda: another storage

Now installing 4 more nvme sticks on 4x PCIe board, while removing 'my storage2', I have following autogenerated mapping.

- /dev/nvme0n1: my boot stick
- /dev/nvme1n1 ~ nvme4n1: 4x PCIe board sticks
- /dev/nvme5n1: my storage1
- /dev/sda: another storage

So far, storage 1, 2 and sda have been mounted by UUID in /etc/fstab, and I thought boot drive was also mounted by UUID, as default.

But after installing 4x PCIe board, the boot sequence goes to maintenanc mode and I have following errors covering the screen that I can't even see menu at all. The msg gets generated in every few seconds whatever I do on terminal.

```
nvme0000:xx:00.0 : AER: aer_status_0x00000001, aer_mask: 0x00000000
nvme0000:xx:00.0 : AER: aer_layer=Physical Layer, aer_agent=Receiver ID
```

'xx' being number such as 42, 43, and 44 in my case. And, in maintenance mode (auto diverted to this mode whenever reboot), in journalctl -xb, I can see that nvme2 is creating some sorta problem. So, I thought it is because nvme mapping is overlapping for one of the new storage sticks that was given to /dev/nvme2n1 and my boot drive's original address, which was /dev/nvme2n1

I thought

```
(sudo) fdisk -y /dev/nvme0n1p1
(sudo) fdisk -y /dev/nvme2n1p1
```

would solve the problem that every restart goes to maintenance mode, given that now nvme0n1 is the new boot drive. But it didn't.

After the hassle, I took the 4x PCIe adapter out, and my current setting is

- /dev/nvme0n1: my boot stick
- /dev/nvme1n1: my storage1
- /dev/sda: another storage

Kinda sorted the issue, but as soon as I add the 4x PCIe adapter, I get the same error again. My guess is that installing everything from scratch could solve the problem, but then I have to do all sorts of migration. Let's say that is the last resort.

I assume 'remap' all nvme sticks for each purpose should be enough. My desired outcome is

- /dev/nvme0n1: my boot stick
- /dev/nvme1n1: my storage1
- /dev/nvme2n1 ~ nvme5n1: 4x PCIe board sticks
- /dev/sda: another storage

The system is Thinkstation P620 (bios updated to most recent, less than a month), Ubuntu 22.04.3 server, and the new 4 nvme sticks are Hynix Platinum P41 2TB.

Comment: This question, as written, resembles an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your actual problem seems that your system won't boot after installing 4 NVME sticks. Attempting to remap device names seems to address a mere symptom. Consider editing your question to focus on your actual problem.